# Pushing items into an array if dates matches - JavaScript/TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

Shorting array to displayed them with respect to date, Like i did - Hiking, shopping on 2020-05-10 and Hiking , Football on 2020-05-10 and similar for other dates.

```
 const items = [
 {title: 'Hiking', date: new Date('2020-05-10')},
 {title: 'Shopping', date: new Date('2020-05-10')},
 //
 {title: 'Hiking', date: new Date('2020-05-22')},
 {title: 'Football', date: new Date('2019-05-22')},
 //
 {title: 'Football', date: new Date('2020-05-28')},
 {title: 'Hiking', date: new Date('2020-05-28')},
 {title: 'Cricket', date: new Date('2020-05-28')},
];
```

Comment: do you need `sorting` based on the date property?

Comment: i want to sort them like below
` 
{
  "2020-05-10": [
    {
      "title": "Hiking"
    },
    {
      "title": "Shopping"
    }
  ],
  "2020-05-22": [
    {
      "title": "Hiking"
    },
    {
      "title": "Football"
    }
  ],
  "2020-05-28": [
    {
      "title": "Hiking"
    },
    {
      "title": "Football"
    },
    {
      "title": "Cricket"
    }
  ]
}
`

Comment: Hello @gorak Can we do something like this with same approach  - [
  {
    "title": "2020-05-21",
    "data": [
      {
        "title": "Hiking"
      },
      {
        "title": "Shopping"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "2020-05-22",
    "data": [
      {
        "title": "Hiking"
      },
      {
        "title": "Shopping"
      }
    ]
  }
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make use of `reduce()`.

```js
var items = [ {title: 'Hiking', date: new Date('2020-05-10')}, {title: 'Shopping', date: new Date('2020-05-10')},{title: 'Hiking', date: new Date('2020-05-22')}, {title: 'Football', date: new Date('2020-05-22')}, {title: 'Football', date: new Date('2020-05-28')}, {title: 'Hiking', date: new Date('2020-05-28')}, {title: 'Cricket', date: new Date('2020-05-28')}];

var result = items.reduce((acc, {title, date})=>{
    dateKey = new Date(date).toISOString().slice(0,10);
    acc[dateKey] = acc[dateKey] || [];
    acc[dateKey].push({title});
    return acc;
},{});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hello @gorak Can we do something like this with same approach - [ { "title": "2020-05-21", "data": [ { "title": "Hiking" }, { "title": "Shopping" } ] }, { "title": "2020-05-22", "data": [ { "title": "Hiking" }, { "title": "Shopping" } ] } ]

Comment: @Jerry Yes, you need to do some change in reduce, `acc[dateKey] = acc[dateKey] || [];` replace with this one-> `acc[dateKey] = acc[dateKey] || {title, data:[]};` and then push in to data.

Comment: it prints date as parent element something like this for the array, which make it complicate can we just have, no date outside as parent -  [
  {
    "title": "2020-05-21",
    "data": [
      {
        "title": "Hiking"
      },
      {
        "title": "Shopping"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "2020-05-22",
    "data": [
      {
        "title": "Hiking"
      },
      {
        "title": "Shopping"
      }
    ]
  }
]

Comment: @Jerry take `Object.values` of `result`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
let items = [
      {title: 'Hiking', date: new Date('2020-05-10')},
      {title: 'Shopping', date: new Date('2020-05-10')},
      {title: 'Hiking', date: new Date('2020-05-22')},
      {title: 'Football', date: new Date('2019-05-22')},
      {title: 'Football', date: new Date('2020-05-28')},
      {title: 'Hiking', date: new Date('2020-05-28')},
      {title: 'Cricket', date: new Date('2020-05-28')},
     ];

    items.sort(function(a,b){
      return a.date - b.date;
    });
    console.log(items);
```

Comment: Thank you but i want to sort them as below -

i want to sort them like below
` 
{
  "2020-05-10": [
    {
      "title": "Hiking"
    },
    {
      "title": "Shopping"
    }
  ],
  "2020-05-22": [
    {
      "title": "Hiking"
    },
    {
      "title": "Football"
    }
  ],
  "2020-05-28": [
    {
      "title": "Hiking"
    },
    {
      "title": "Football"
    },
    {
      "title": "Cricket"
    }
  ]
}
`